Whenever audio plays it cuts out and is replaced with loud continuous beeping that only stops when I stop the thing playing audio
As the title says, whenever audio plays for more than a few minutes, my computer makes a loud continuous beeping noise that only stops when the program playing the audio stops.
I've done a bit of searching and found some supposed fixes, and none of them did much of anything. I tried adding options snd_sof sof_debug=1 to the /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf file, and running the line:
wget -qO- https://gist.github.com/heikomat/3fe272431b44b580c933bfb901a92257/raw | bash

as those were the only things I found, but neither of them did much of anything.
I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling libasound2 and files having to do with it, which didn't do anything except deleting my settings app.
My OS is Ubuntu 24.04 running from a persistent USB.
Audio device:
Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 35).

There is a problem with certain sound cards, the cause of which has not been identified yet and may never be identified, as you can read in this GitHub issue: [[BUG]BYT][CHT] Linux 5.11 Cherrytrail/rt5640 emits persistent beeping sound after a short while
However there is a workaround:

Add the line options snd_sof sof_debug=1 at the end of /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf file.
Completely shutdown and start the system.

Adding the options above may cause freezing of the sound. The workaround is:

Replace the line options snd_sof sof_debug=1 with options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=2.
Completely shutdown and start the system.

